Calibration curves from coxph() in R
I am running cox PH survival analyses for diabetes as an outcome, with <10 variables and no interaction terms. The c stats are all consistent with the literature sitting at around 0.75-0.80, as expected. However, I am struggling to print calibration curves, as although the per decile points appear to be in essentially a diagonal line, the scale of the axes aren't correct as the x=y is almost completely vertical. Here is the code that I have used:
# Function to fit Cox model, predict risk, calculate AUROC, and C-statistic
fit_cox_model <- function(train_data, test_data, event_var) {
  cox_model <- coxph(Surv(time_to_event, get(event_var)) ~ age_at_reference + smoking_category +
                       waist_mm + hypertension_diag + glucose_log + fam_hist_binary, 
                     data = train_data)
  print(summary(cox_model))
  
  test_data$pred_risk <- predict(cox_model, newdata = test_data, type = "risk")
  
  # Calculate AUROC
  roc_curve <- roc(test_data[[event_var]], test_data$pred_risk)
  auroc <- auc(roc_curve)
  ci_auroc <- ci.auc(roc_curve)
  
  # Calculate C-statistic and its standard error
  c_stat <- summary(cox_model)$concordance[1]
  c_stat_se <- summary(cox_model)$concordance[2]
  c_stat_ci_lower <- c_stat - 1.96 * c_stat_se
  c_stat_ci_upper <- c_stat + 1.96 * c_stat_se
  
  return(list(auroc = auroc, lower_ci_auroc = ci_auroc[1], upper_ci_auroc = ci_auroc[3],
              c_stat = c_stat, c_stat_ci_lower = c_stat_ci_lower, c_stat_ci_upper = c_stat_ci_upper,
              test_data = test_data))
}

Then for the calibration plots:
# Function to plot calibration curves per decile
plot_calibration_curve <- function(test_data, censoring_var, title_suffix) {
  test_data <- test_data %>%
    mutate(decile = ntile(pred_risk, 10)) %>%
    group_by(decile) %>%
    summarise(pred_risk_mean = mean(pred_risk), events = sum(get(censoring_var)), count = n()) %>%
    mutate(observed_prob = events / count)
  
  ggplot(test_data, aes(x = pred_risk_mean, y = observed_prob)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
    labs(title = paste("Calibration Curve -", title_suffix),
         x = "Mean Predicted Risk",
         y = "Observed Probability") +
    theme_minimal()
}

As can be seen in the attached image, the mean predicted risks are all above one, it appears to be well calibrated the scale is just off. Should I be using cph()? I have tried to do so but am struggling to get it to run, datadist() is causing issues. Any guidance would be appreciated! Thanks.
I have tried to use cph() instead of coxph() as it has an inbuilt calibration curve function, but am struggling to get it to run, datadist() is causing issues.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. If you are looking for modeling advice, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead.

If datadist use is causing "issues" then you should post code and the complete error messages or warnings or unexpected results might be.
